# DataGridTextColumn style with wrap and tooltip

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid, wpf-style

In my C# / WPF application, I have a `Datagrid` with several `DataGridTextColumn` column using both text wrapping and a tooltip.

I could write each column like this (and this works fine):

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}">
    <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
        <Style>
            <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextWrapping" Value="Wrap" />
        </Style>
    </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
    <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
            <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="Some tooltip text" />
        </Style>
    </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

But I would like to define a common style that can set both the wrapping and the tooltip text, knowing that the tooltip text will be different for each column. The purpose is to avoid code redundancy and make it clearer.

So far, here's my style:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="WrapStyle" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
        <Style.Setters>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Content.Text}" TextWrapping="Wrap">
                            <TextBox.ToolTip>
                                <ToolTip>
                                    <ToolTip.Content>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Tooltip}" />
                                    </ToolTip.Content>
                                </ToolTip>
                            </TextBox.ToolTip>
                        </TextBox>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style.Setters>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

And my column:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}" CellStyle="{StaticResource WrapStyle}" />
```

The problem is that I can't specify a tooltip to pass to the style. Is there a way to do it without writing 5 lines of `DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle` for each column?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Modify the style to -

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="WrapStyle" TargetType="DataGridCell">
        <Style.Setters>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Content.Text}" TextWrapping="Wrap">
                            <TextBox.ToolTip>
                                <ToolTip>
                                    <ToolTip.Content>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Tooltip}"></TextBlock>
                                    </ToolTip.Content>
                                </ToolTip>
                            </TextBox.ToolTip>
                        </TextBox>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style.Setters>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

Comment: How do you pass the tooltip text to the style from the DataGridTextColumn ? It doesn't accept a tooltip parameter

Comment: Tooltip can be a property of the Item that is currently bound. ie. if collection of Student is bound as items source and Student class has Tooltip property, you can set it as tooltip as shown above.

Comment: @piyush Can you tell me how to use above style in **DataGridTextColumn**..You explained it in previous comment but I did not understnad it.  Here is how it will be defined, Im trying to understand how can we pass the tooltip text to this style?  <DataGridTextColumn Header="Amount" Width="200" Binding="{Binding EmployeeClass.amount}" CellStyle="{StaticResource WrapStyle}" />